# Height of 1 div depending on height of other div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following scenario: I want Div2's height to resize depending on the content of Div3, and Div3's height to resize depending on content on Div2. The height of Div1 is 500px and fixed.

I have the following doubts:

- Is it advisable doing it this way, as it requires calculations of height based on content?
- Can we do it using CSS?

```
+-------------+
|  DIV1(500px)|
|  +-------+  |
|  |       |  |
|  |  DIV2 |  |
|  |       |  |
|  |       |  |
|  +-------+  |
|  +-------+  |
|  |       |  |
|  |  DIV3 |  |
|  |       |  |
|  |       |  |
|  |       |  |
|  |       |  |
|  +-------+  |
+-------------+
```

Comment: what about if DIV2 or DIV3 content height exceeds 500px?

Comment: Try with viewport heights. It helps to control other div sizes as well.

Comment: @ozil: We have to get scrollbars in each div(div2,div3). If both of them more data then both should take the height equally with scrollbars.

Comment: you need to check height of each div's content take, compare them and assign height to each accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to decide if the height of Div2 should be based on the height of Div3 or vice-versa.  They cannot be based on each others' height, because there are infinite solutions to this system of equations:

```
x = 500 - y
y = 500 - x
```

Here's a flex solution, where `D3` is based on the height of `D2`:

```
#D1 {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#D2 {
  overflow: auto;
}

#D3 {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

If `D2` should be based on the height of `D3`, move `flex: 1;` to `D2`'s style.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ye4or93d/)

Answer (score -1):

What you describe is not possible with css. You could do it by hand with javascript, but I would recommend looking at [Grid stylesheets](http://gridstylesheets.org/). In ccss, the rule would be

```
#div2[height] + #div3[height] = 500
```